# Attribute value is not coming on my cart page, fetching all the attributes

Tags: magento2

On my website i want to display value of an attribute, but when i m trying to display, site goes blank.
On my cart page i want to display details of my products feature
Given below is the code to fetch all the attributes name

```
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach($attributes as $a)
{
    echo $a->getName()."\n";
    
}
```

I have written this code in default.phtml
i m getting below output , i.e name of the attribute
but i want the value of the attribute
how to achieve it
[image]

**Tried methods**
$product->getAttributeText('features');
$a->getData();

Answer (score 0):

`$product->getAttributeText('features');` does only work for attributes of type "select".

`$product->getData('features');` should do the trick.

Comment: Its not working for me.

Comment: `features` is the attribute code? Is this attribute set to "visible in checkout" and "visible in product listing"? If not, try it.

Comment: FYI $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) worked for me